# How To Center Pre-Loader (Mobile)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, preloader

Tried a ton of different solutions but for some reason can't center my pre-loader when on mobile. It is fine on desktop / Mobile Landscape, but whenever I am on Mobile Portrait....it's not centred.

**CSS:**

```
    .load-screen{
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.loading-image{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 15vw;
    margin-left: auto;
    animation-name: loadscreen;
    animation-duration: 3.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;

}
```

**Screenshot:**
[Mobile Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ur20f.jpg)

Comment: Post the HTML too.

Comment: `align-items` and `justify-content` doesn't work unless you have `display:flex` btw.

Comment: The likely hood of the problem is that you're missing `margin-right: auto` on `.load-screen` - so it pushes off to the left but nothing is pushing from the right back into the center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using display:flex will make anything inside it a flex item.
justify-content: center will center the item left to right
align items: center will center the item top to bottom.

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fm3xvzc8/

```
.load-screen{
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: auto;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 0.4s ease-in;
}

.loading-image{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    // margin-top: 15vw; The margins aren't necessary
    // margin-left: auto; The margins aren't necessary
    animation-name: loadscreen;
    animation-duration: 3.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}
```